# Rotation of 15 people at five tables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-designs

I have five tables of four people each.  At each table is a table leader who remains stationery. How do I rotate the 15 participants so that they get to meet new people each time they rotate?